# Is there any way to open all types of files (.txt, .doc, .ppt, .xlsx etc) in python

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

i can open any .txt file by this code

```
userinput1  = input ("Enter file name:")
myfile1 = open(userinput1).read()
print(myfile1)
```

but when i open any pdf or ppt or xlsx file it gives error.anyone help me or tell me any way to open all types of files (.txt, .doc, .ppt, .xlsx etc) in python

Output:

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/umer/Desktop/stack.py", line 33, in <module>
    myfile1 = open(userinput1).read()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 370: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: @Stefan Pochmann                                                                      
Output:                                                                                     
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/umer/Desktop/stack.py", line 33, in <module>
    myfile1 = open(userinput1).read()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 370: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: You need a different library for each of the types you list. They are all binary formats, containing all kinds of information (eg., PDF can contain images, audio, even video; xlsx may contain diagrams) stored in very different ways. It highly depends on what you actually want to do with the information, but most likely you'll need a separate approach for each file type.

Comment: Of course you can read them in binary mode: `open(userinput1, 'rb').read()`, but that will simply return a blob of binary data, which isn't useful in most cases.

Comment: then how to convert that binary code into text ?? @lenz

Comment: You need a library for that. Search the Internet for "python extract text from PDF". Repeat the search for each file format you want to support.

Comment: What do you want to do with the files you open? The answer to your question depends on that.

Comment: @alexis i am making plagiarism checker desktop tool .i want to match the input file from user with the files in the folder one by one to check similarity between files.user will input pdf file and i have to check similarity of user file with pdf files in folder.thats why i want to open, extract text from pdf

Comment: Then you need to use an appropriate library for each file type you need to handle (as @lenz wrote), and the answer you accepted is actually useless to you. Note also that it is extremely difficult to extract text reliably from PDF; it is a surprisingly low-level format. You get a stream of letters and their positions, and the extractor has to guess (not always correctly) where the word boundaries are.

Answer (score 0):

There's no universal answer to this, because every file has its own encoding, so for reading and writing, you need to know which encoding to use.

You could for example use

```
import codecs
userinput1  = input ("Enter file name:")
myfile1 = codecs.open(userinput1, "r", "latin-1").read()
print(myfile1)
```

but you will still need to know which encoding the file has and change it accordingly (in this example it's `latin-1`).

Comment: what is the encoding of pdf file or how to know encoding of file?? @Stefan pochmann

Comment: The question is about much more than encoding: it's about accessing (textual?) information contained in binary formats. That's a different story than just specifying the input encoding of a text file.

Comment: import codecs
userinput1  = input ("Enter file name:")
myfile1 = codecs.open(userinput1, "r", "latin-1").read()
print(myfile1)    by this code i opened pdf file but its shows symbols like this "9Ud5cDcTGÓfÃ" .how to convert it into text format and display @lenz